# Removing DOM nodes when traversing a NodeList

Tags: java, xml, dom

I'm about to delete certain elements in an XML document, using code like the following:

```
NodeList nodes = ...;
for (int i = 0; i < nodes.getLength(); i++) {
  Element e = (Element)nodes.item(i);
  if (certain criteria involving Element e) {
    e.getParentNode().removeChild(e);
  }
}
```

Will this interfere with proper traversal of the NodeList?  Any other caveats with this approach?  If this is totally wrong, what's the proper way to do it?

Answer (score 16):

Removing nodes while looping will cause undesirable results, e.g. either missed or duplicated results. This isn't even an issue with synchronization and thread safety, but if the nodes are modified by the loop itself. Most of Java's Iterator's will throw a ConcurrentModificationException in such a case, something that NodeList does not account for.

It can be fixed by decrementing NodeList size and by decrementing iteraror pointer at the same time. This solution can be used only if we proceed one remove action for each loop iteration.

```
NodeList nodes = ...;
for (int i = nodes.getLength() - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
  Element e = (Element)nodes.item(i);
   if (certain criteria involving Element e) {
    e.getParentNode().removeChild(e);
  }
}
```

Comment: wow... best answer ever... so much thing in just the way a for loop is traversed !

Answer (score 11):

So, given that removing nodes while traversing the NodeList will cause the NodeList to be updated to reflect the new reality, I assume that my indices will become invalid and this will not work.

So, it seems the solution is to keep track of the elements to delete during the traversal, and delete them all afterward, once the NodeList is no longer used.

```
NodeList nodes = ...;
Set<Element> targetElements = new HashSet<Element>();
for (int i = 0; i < nodes.getLength(); i++) {
  Element e = (Element)nodes.item(i);
  if (certain criteria involving Element e) {
    targetElements.add(e);
  }
}
for (Element e: targetElements) {
  e.getParentNode().removeChild(e);
}
```

Comment: Why do you feel the need to do this? Do your criteria depend on the element's siblings? If yes (in other words, if-and-only-if you need to preserve the siblings) then keep a List (there's no need for Set, there aren't going to be duplicates).

Comment: Criteria doesn't depend on the siblings, but if I understand the answer above, if I delete node 5 out of 7, suddenly I'll only have 6 nodes in my NodeList, and my for loop will have wrong indices, skipping one Node and then advancing past the end of the list.  Please correct me if I'm misunderstanding.

Comment: Why do you say "No need for a Set"?  Isn't it the other way around?  There's no need for a List, since order doesn't matter, so I just used a Set.

Comment: What this means is that the NodeList will return nodes in order. Removing a node from the middle of that list will shift the indices, but only for nodes that you've not yet visited. And since your loop uses getLength(), you're never going to index off the end of the list.

Comment: As for using a List instead of a Set (which is a moot point). Since order matters, you want to preserve that order. In this case, maybe it's not so important, but it almost every other case it will be. Plus, list implementations tend to be more efficient than set implementations.

Comment: The order in which I remove the nodes doesn't matter, does it?

Comment: Okay, suppose out of 5 nodes, 0-4 I remove node 2.  Now my next iteration will skip the former node 3 (now node 2), assuming I remove nodes during the loop.  So don't I have to put them all in a collection (or something) and remove them outside of the loop?  I don't understand the points you've been trying to make.  So therefore, I'm fearful that I'm missing something. :)

Comment: OK, I see what you're saying now. Count backwards.

Comment: Ah, I see!  So I just need to change the for loop to for (int i = nodes.getLength() - 1; i >= 0; i--) , and then I won't need the collection?  Makes perfect sense.  Post it, re-explaining why the original doesn't work, and I'll mark you as the accepted answer. :)

Comment: Marking the nodes, writing to a set and then subsequently removing does the trick.  Do the comments on this thread show an issue with the solution in this answer?

Answer (score 7):

According to the DOM specificaion, the result of a call to *node.getElementsByTagName("...")* is supposed to be "live", that is, any modification made to the DOM tree will be reflected in the *NodeList* object. Well, for conforming implementations, that is...

> NodeList and NamedNodeMap objects in
>   the DOM are live; that is, changes to
>   the underlying document structure are
>   reflected in all relevant NodeList and
>   NamedNodeMap  objects.

([DOM Specification](http://www.w3.org/TR/2004/REC-DOM-Level-3-Core-20040407/core.html#ID-1590626202))

So, when you modify the tree structure, a conforming implementation will change the *NodeList* to reflect these changes.

Comment: So that would mean my indexes become invalid during the traversal, right?

Comment: @Dirk, appart from referencing the important information regarding DOM NodeList specs and Java's implementation of it... this answer doesn't offer a conclusive statement in regards to the question..

Answer (score 1):

The [Practical XML](https://sourceforge.net/projects/practicalxml/) library now contains [NodeListIterator](http://practicalxml.sourceforge.net/apidocs/net/sf/practicalxml/util/NodeListIterator.html), which wraps a NodeList and provides full Iterator support (this seemed like a better choice than posting the code that we discussed in the comments). If you don't want to use the full library, feel free to copy that one class: http://practicalxml.svn.sourceforge.net/viewvc/practicalxml/trunk/src/main/java/net/sf/practicalxml/util/NodeListIterator.java?revision=125&view=markup

Answer (score 1):

According to the DOM Level 3 Core specification,

the result of a call to method `node.getElementsByTagName("...")` will be a reference to a "***live***" `NodeList` type.

> NodeList and NamedNodeMap objects in the DOM are live; that is, changes to the underlying document structure are reflected in all relevant NodeList and NamedNodeMap  objects.
>   ... changes are automatically reflected in the NodeList, without further action on the user's part.
>
> [1.1.1 The DOM Structure Model, para. 2](http://www.w3.org/TR/2004/REC-DOM-Level-3-Core-20040407/core.html#td-live)

---

JavaSE 7 conforms to the DOM Level 3 specification: it implements the ***live*** [NodeList](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/org/w3c/dom/NodeList.html) interface and defines it as a type; it defines and exposes `getElementsByTagName` method on [Interface Element](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/org/w3c/dom/Element.html), which returns the ***live*** `NodeList` type.

---

#### References

[W3C - Document Object Model (DOM) Level 3 Core Specification - `getElementsByTagName`](http://www.w3.org/TR/2004/REC-DOM-Level-3-Core-20040407/core.html#ID-A6C9094)

[JavaSE 7 - Interface Element](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/org/w3c/dom/Element.html)

[JavaSE 7 - NodeList Type](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/org/w3c/dom/NodeList.html)

Answer (score 1):

Old post, but nothing marked as answer. My approach is to iterate from the end, ie

```
for (int i = nodes.getLength() - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
    // do processing, and then
    e.getParentNode().removeChild(e);
}
```

With this, you needn't worry about the NodeList getting shorter while you delete.

Answer (score 0):

As already mentioned, removing an element reduces the size of the list but the counter is still increasing (i++):

```
[element 1] <- Delete 
[element 2]
[element 3]
[element 4]
[element 5]

[element 2]  
[element 3] <- Delete
[element 4]
[element 5]
--

[element 2]  
[element 4] 
[element 5] <- Delete
--
--

[element 2]  
[element 4] 
--
--
--
```

**The simplest solution, in my opinion, would be to remove i++ section in the loop and do it as needed when the iterated element was not deleted.**

```
NodeList nodes = ...;
for (int i = 0; i < nodes.getLength();) {
  Element e = (Element)nodes.item(i);
  if (certain criteria involving Element e) {
    e.getParentNode().removeChild(e);        
  } else {
    i++;
  }
}
```

Pointer stays on the same place when the iterated element was deleted. The list shifts by itself.

```
[element 1] <- Delete 
[element 2]
[element 3]
[element 4]
[element 5]

[element 2] <- Leave
[element 3]
[element 4]
[element 5]
--

[element 2] 
[element 3] <- Leave
[element 4]
[element 5]
--

[element 2] 
[element 3] 
[element 4] <- Delete
[element 5]
--

[element 2] 
[element 3] 
[element 5] <- Delete
--
--

[element 2] 
[element 3] 
--
--
--
```

Answer (score 0):

At the end, you must update the XML file within the path of your project.

```
TransformerFactory transFactory = TransformerFactory.newInstance();
Transformer transformer = transFactory.newTransformer();
DOMSource source = new DOMSource(documentoXml);
StreamResult result = new StreamResult(new File(path + "\\resources\\xml\\UsuariosFile.xml"));
transformer.transform(source, result);
```

if you do not put these lines, your file will not be updated