# Replace values in a list of objects with xpath?

Tags: java, xml, xpath

Is xpath capable to replace values of a xml doc?

The following gets all name elements, but how could I replace them?

```
<accounts>
<account>
<name>Johndoe1<name>
<account>
<account>
<name>Johndoe2<name>
<account>
</account>

XPathExpression fax = xpath.compile("/accounts/account/name")
Object result = expr.evaluate(doc, XPathConstants.NODESET);
NodeList nodes = (NodeList) result;
for (int i = 0; i < nodes.getLength(); i++) {
    System.out.println(nodes.item(i).getNodeValue()); 
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is xpath capable to replace values of a xml doc?

No, XPath is a *query* language for XML documents. As such it only extracts node and data from XML documents, but cannot alter (add, replace, delete, a node) the XML document.

When the processing of an XML document results in the creation of another XML document that is different from the original, this is called *XML transformation*. XSLT is a language especially designed for XML transformations and is the most natural choice for such processing.

Answer (score 1):

XPath merely identifies the nodes in a document. You'll have to use the DOM api to remove those elements. See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1374088/removing-dom-nodes-when-traversing-a-nodelist) for more info on how to remove elements whilst traversing a `NodeList`.