# removeChild() method is breaking for loop

Tags: java, xml, jakarta-ee, jaxp

I am using following code to remove multiple elements from XMl file.

```
NodeList removeNodeList = doc.getElementsByTagName("server1");
Element rootElement = doc.getDocumentElement();

for (int i = 0; i < removeNodeList.getLength(); i++) {
    rootElement.removeChild(removeNodeList.item(i));
}
```

But after removing one element it is coming out of loop. What is the issue.

Following is my XML file content.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no"?>
<start>

    <category name="server1"/>
    <category name="server2"/>

    <server1 name="serverName1" value="serverValue"/>
    <server1 name="serverName1" value="serverValue"/>

    <server2 name="serverName2" value="serverValue"/>

</start>
```

Comment: I'd guess the `NodeList` is dynamic and removing an element updates (reduces) the length, resulting in your loop condition only evaluating to true the first time. That's primarily based on the way they work in JavaScript, though, I have no experience working with XML documents in Java.

Comment: have you checked few things like - length of removeNodeList. And what are the contents of xml after executing for loop, is it removing only one element?

Comment: @csn thanks for the reply, I have checked the size of `NodeList`, its 2 before then it reduce to 1.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found the solution:

Let me explain what was the problem in detail.

`NodeList removeNodeList = doc.getElementsByTagName("server1");`
`removeNodeList.getLength()` will return 2 as there are 2 nodes with nodeName `server1` then after executing `rootElement.removeChild(removeNodeList.item(i));` and then checking `for loop` condition `i.e.` the value of `i` is `1` and `removeNodeList.getLength()` returns `1` as now only 1 node with nodeName `server1` is remaining in `DOM document` and this condition was failing as `1 < 1 is false`

So I followed the following approach:

Delete all the elements afterwards once the NodeList is no longer used.

```
NodeList nodes = doc.getElementsByTagName(elementName);
Set<Element> targetElements = new HashSet<Element>();

for (int i = 0; i < nodes.getLength(); i++) {
    Element e = (Element)nodes.item(i);
    targetElements.add(e);
}
for (Element e: targetElements) {
    e.getParentNode().removeChild(e);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Removing an element from the list decrements its size by 1 which breaks the iteration. You need to iterate the list backwards (from last to first node) as described in this question:

[Removing DOM nodes when traversing a NodeList](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1374088/removing-dom-nodes-when-traversing-a-nodelist)

Answer (score 0):

As already mentioned, removing an element reduces the size of the list but the counter is still increasing (i++):

```
[element 1] <- Delete 
[element 2]
[element 3]
[element 4]
[element 5]

[element 2]  
[element 3] <- Delete
[element 4]
[element 5]
--

[element 2]  
[element 4] 
[element 5] <- Delete
--
--

[element 2]  
[element 4] 
--
--
--
```

**The simplest solution, in my opinion, would be to remove i++ section in the loop.**

```
for (int i = 0; i < removeNodeList.getLength();) {
    rootElement.removeChild(removeNodeList.item(i));
}
```

Pointer stays on the same place.
The list shifts by itself.

```
[element 1] <- Delete 
[element 2]
[element 3]
[element 4]
[element 5]

[element 2] <- Delete 
[element 3]
[element 4]
[element 5]
--

[element 3] <- Delete 
[element 4]
[element 5]
--
--

[element 4] <- Delete 
[element 5]
--
--
--

[element 5] <- Delete 
--
--
--
--
```

Answer (score 0):

#### To remove all elements contained in removeNodeList from xml-document:

Because the node is also removed from `removeNodeList` the next node to remove is on index 0 in `removeNodeList` until the list is empty (`removeNodeList.getLength() == 0`)

```
while(removeNodeList.getLength() > 0) {
    rootElement.removeChild(removeNodeList.item(0));
}
```

This works only if each node `"server1"` is a child of the node `"start"`.
If the xml would contain `"server1"` nodes as child of a node different from node `rootElement` ("start") a DOMException would be thrown because the node to remove is not a child of `rootElement`.
For example:

```
<category name="server1"/>
<category name="server2"/>

<server1 name="serverName1" value="serverValue"/>
<other>
   <server1 name="serverName1" value="serverValue"/>
</other>

<server2 name="serverName2" value="serverValue"/>
```

To handle this case get the parent node of the item to remove:

```
while(removeNodeList.getLength() > 0) {
    Node itemToRemove = removeNodeList.item(0);
    itemToRemove.getParentNode().removeChild(itemToRemove);
}
```

#### To remove elements conditionally, for example based on some attribute value:

Node will be removed only if method `shouldRemoveNode()` returns true.
If false the node remains in document and `removeNodeList`, the next node to (possibly) remove is on index = current index + 1
`notRemovedCnt` is both the number of nodes not removed and also the index of the next element to check if it should be removed, 
as long until `removeNodeList` length and `notRemoveCnt` are equal which means no more elements to remove in list.

```
int notRemovedCnt = 0;
while(removeNodeList.getLength() > notRemovedCnt) {
    Node itemToRemove = removeNodeList.item(notRemovedCnt);
    if (shouldRemoveNode(itemToRemove)) {
        itemToRemove.getParentNode().removeChild(itemToRemove); 
    } else {
        notRemovedCnt++;
    }
}
```