# Unable to Delete Nodes

Tags: java, xml, dom, sax

After a lot of attempts, I got this code working. But unfortunately i am not able to delete the nodes. My input and output XML are exactly the same.

```
 private void removeEmptyChildElements(Document doc) throws TransformerFactoryConfigurationError, TransformerException {
      NodeList nodeList = doc.getElementsByTagName("item");

    for (int i=0; i<nodeList.getLength(); i++) {
        Node node = nodeList.item(i);

        if (node.getAttributes().getNamedItem("text").getNodeValue().equals("PAL")) {

            if (node.hasChildNodes()) {
                node.getParentNode().removeChild(node);
            }               
        } else if (node.getAttributes().getNamedItem("text").getNodeValue().equals("HAL")) {

            if (node.hasChildNodes()) {
                node.getParentNode().removeChild(node);
            }               
        } else if (node.getAttributes().getNamedItem("text").getNodeValue().equals("fName")) {

            if (node.hasChildNodes()) {
                node.getParentNode().removeChild(node);
            }               
        } else if (node.getAttributes().getNamedItem("text").getNodeValue().equals("LName")) {

            if (node.hasChildNodes()) {
                node.getParentNode().removeChild(node);
            }               
        }
    }

StringWriter sw = new StringWriter(); 
     Transformer serializer = TransformerFactory.newInstance().newTransformer(); 
     serializer.transform(new DOMSource(nodeList.item(0)), new StreamResult(sw));   
     String result = sw.toString(); 
     System.out.println(result);
}
```

At the start I have 62 nodes, in the end i am expecting max 51 nodes.

Comment: You're missing a quotation mark and a lot of your code is being made into a string. Is that your problem?

Comment: Not sure. I tried to format the post the best i can.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Removing DOM nodes when traversing a NodeList](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1374088/removing-dom-nodes-when-traversing-a-nodelist)

Comment: Thanks Raman, that worked! :)